# Compiling Unify.c for Logitech wireless keyboard and mouse error - how to use both the keyboard and mouse on the same receiver?

Tags: wireless, mouse, logitech, wireless-keyboards, logitech-unifying

I bought this [Logitech Wireless Keyboard K360](http://www.logitech.com/en-ca/keyboards/keyboards/keyboard-k360)

and this [Logitech Wireless Mouse M505](http://www.logitech.com/en-ca/mice-pointers/mice/wireless-mouse-m505)

I am trying to use both on the same receiver, but so far I can't figure it out!

I have tried [this](https://github.com/treeder/logitech_unifier)

But I don't know how to compile it!

If I paste `gcc -o unify unify.c` in the terminal, then I got this:

```
gcc: erreur: unify.c: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type gcc: erreur
fatale: pas de fichier à l'entrée compilation terminée.

Translated (edited)

gcc: error: unify.c: No such file or directory that type gcc: error
  fatal: no input file to compile is complete ..
```

sorry it is in french (edited). It says no files of this type and no file in the input.

Can anyone  tell me how to compile it and then find my hidraw devices??

Comment: I think you have to download the unify.c file from that website. Going to try this myself tonight

Comment: Try browsing to the directory or folder in which you have stored unify.c , then try compiling from there.

Comment: Simon, you have to download the source file before you can compile it. Your title is asking how to pair new devices, there is already an answer on other questions.